# Launching WPF application through output file

Tags: wpf

Suppose that I have a WPF application that outputs files with extension ".test". If I had 2 files, a.test and b.test, each loading data from their own database file, what can I use (in C#)  to make the WPF application load the data associated with "a" if a.test is double clicked?

I would like it to work just like Microsoft Word does in which clicking on a .doc document launches the Word application and loads the corresponding text saved with that file.

Any help you can provide will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It is an Option in Windows Installer to associate File types to the application. Also You could achieve this by **Right Click** + **Open with** option and associate the application to the file extension. 
Second part is to implement application command line arguments. When you double click on the file, windows shell essentially forms the file as an argument to the app.
Here is a [Quick Tutorial](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/avip/archive/2008/10/27/wpf-supporting-command-line-arguments-and-file-extensions.aspx).

Comment: @Glad... you got the answer... in that case can you mark it as an answer please.. that will help other to guide that this is the right answer :)